# ReactJS template literal as variable name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I'm wondering if it's possible to evaluate a templateLiteral as a variable name and then use it to reference an import.

So far this is my code:

```
//These are redux action types
import * as fileTypeOneActions from "./fileTypeOne/actionTypes"
import * as fileTypeTwoActions from "./fileTypeTwo/actionTypes"
import * as fileTypeThreeActions from "./fileTypeThree/actionTypes"

export const updateApiResponse = (reducer, apiResponse) => {  

//reducer can be"fileTypeOne", "fileTypeTwo", or "fileTypeThree" as arguments

    const reducerKey = eval(`${reducer}Actions`)
    
    return {
        type: reducerKey.UPDATE_API_RESPONSE,
        apiResponse: apiResponse,
      }
}
```

Based on the string passed as 'reducer' argument, I want to reference the correct import and return correct redux action type as such. Any ideas?

the eval statement above is not working.

Comment: 1.) use descriptive names, 2) never use eval - especially if you need to ask stackoverlow about it

Answer (score 0):

```
//These are redux action types
import * as fileTypeOneActions from "./fileTypeOne/actionTypes"
import * as fileTypeTwoActions from "./fileTypeTwo/actionTypes"
import * as fileTypeThreeActions from "./fileTypeThree/actionTypes"
const reducerMap = {
  1:fileTypeOneActions,
  2:fileTypeTwoActions,
  3:fileTypeThreeActions
}
export const updateApiResponse = (reducer, apiResponse) => {  

//reducer can be"fileTypeOne", "fileTypeTwo", or "fileTypeThree" as arguments

    //const reducerKey = eval(`${reducer}Actions`)
      const reducerKey = reducerMap(reducer) // reducer can be 1,2,3 or any other key
    
    return {
        type: reducerKey.UPDATE_API_RESPONSE,
        apiResponse: apiResponse,
      }
}
```

try to avoid eval. It's too dangerous.

Comment: This will work but I'm looking for a more dynamic solution

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different version that maps better to the input you have:

```
//These are redux action types
import * as fileTypeOneActions from "./fileTypeOne/actionTypes"
import * as fileTypeTwoActions from "./fileTypeTwo/actionTypes"
import * as fileTypeThreeActions from "./fileTypeThree/actionTypes"

const actions = {
  fileTypeOneActions,
  fileTypeTwoActions,
  fileTypeThreeActions
};

export const updateApiResponse = (reducer, apiResponse) => {  
    const reducerKey = actions[`${reducer}Actions`];
    return {
        type: reducerKey.UPDATE_API_RESPONSE,
        apiResponse: apiResponse,
      }
}
```

Using an object as a map is the way to go. I don't see how this isn't dynamic (as claimed in your comment to the other answer).

Comment: Thanks Felix - I wasn't clear about the dynamic aspect. In this application we're constanty adding reducers, therefore actions, so that actions object would need to be manually updated.

Comment: Since you already have to import them, why is updating the object a problem? If you want to you can create a separate module that exports all those actions as named exports (`export * as fileTypeOneActions from '...';`) and then import that module instead (`import * as actions from '...'`).